# Why does __uint8_t exist?

Tags: c, types, libc

To better understand how libc works, I was reading the FreeBSD source code. And there I stumbled upon the definition of __uint8_t in the sys/_types.h file. I can understand definitions of types like u_int8_t for compatibility with old code, but a special _types.h file where all types start with __? Why are these types defined in the _types.h file that accompanies types.h and not just types.h altogheter with other types like standard uint8_t?

(I assume that these types with __ at the beginning are not defined to be compatible with the old code because it is not written in the comment)

Comment: @user4581301 I haven't followed that link, but it is worth noting that double-underscore rules differ between C and C++.  C only reserves identifiers that start with the double-underscore (or Underscore followed by Capital), while C++ reserves all identifiers that use a double underscore no matter where it appears.

Comment: On second thought, since the question's about libc, I'm going to pull the link and the C++ tag.

Comment: Just a thought: *libc* is part of the implementation for a specific environment. The rules for writing the Standard Library (*free-standing* environment) are different than for writing *hosted programs*. Again just a thought.

Comment: I don't know for sure; but FreBSD's source code has a very long history (dating back to original BSD from 1970s) and `stdint.h` is much newer (maybe 2001?); so it's possible that FreeBSD was using their "non-standard" types before there was a standard, and just kept on using them (to avoid changing everything) after `stdint.h` was introduced.

Comment: @Brendan The fixed width (and fast/least variants) were introduced in the C99 standard.

Comment: *but a special _types.h file where all types start with __?* That's not a question. What exactly do you find troublesome in this file?  *Why are these types defined in the _types.h* For the internal needs of the implementation. *that accompanies types.h* Not as far as standard-conforming user programs are concerned. To them, _types.h simply doesn't exist. *and not just types.h* Probably for the same reason the standard library is not all lumped into one header: manageability. But that's just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does __uint8_t exist?

To provide access to the implementation's 8-bit unsigned type that does not collide with user code.

---

> a special _types.h file where all types start with __

`__` names are reserved by the implementation, so using that name will not collide with user code.

---

> Why are these types defined in the _types.h file that accompanies types.h and not just types.h altogether with other types like standard `uint8_t`?

So the implementation can include its include its own files without including the various STD C .h files.

`uint8_t` is defiifned in `<stdint.h>`.  Defining `__xxx_t` in there too would bring in definitions other definitions that may conflict with user code.  Compliant user code is *not* required to include `<stdint.h>`.